# I can't do domain painting

Tags: dns, migration, subdomain, dnsmasq

I transferred this website (hustleupdate.com) today from another hosting to Namecheap using DNS address. And the notification says that it may take up to 48 hours for everything to be fixed. But after a while, I see the website is not loading.

And this is the first time I've done this

[image: DNS problem]

Answer (score 0):

You said "after a while, I see the website is not loading", but did you wait 48 hours?

I can see that your domain name is resolving right now.

I think you just needed to wait for the propagation to complete, just as the message said.